# Tkinter mainloop and image packing must be in the same code section?

Tags: python, tkinter

The following example simply won't display the image:

```
from tkinter import *

def main(root):
    img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")
    Label(image=img).pack()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

But if I move `mainloop` into `main` or execute them outside function it would work:

```
root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")
Label(image=img).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also tried to use `grid` but has the same issue.
Could someone explain the reason behind this, or am I missing something?

Comment: common bug with `Garbage Collector` in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when image is assigned to local variable (varaible created in function). You have to assign image to global variable or other class - ie. `label = Label(...)` and `label.img = PhotoImage(..)`

Comment: The image is not shown because it is garbage collected after the function returns.  However if you put `mainloop()` into `main()`, the function does not return because `mainloop()` blocks the application.  In this case the image can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

It is common problem with bug in `PhotoImage` with `Garbage Collector` which removes image from memory when image is assigned to local variable (variable created in function). You have to assign image to global variable or to some object - ie. to label which displays image:

```
label = Label(...)
label.img = PhotoImage(..)
```

---

Minimal working examples

```
from tkinter import *

def main(root):
    global img  # <-- solution for bug 

    img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")
    Label(image=img).pack()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

or

```
from tkinter import *

def main(root):
    img = PhotoImage(file="image.png")
    label = Label(image=img)
    label.pack()

    label.img = img  # <-- solution for bug 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Not so long time ago you could find this information in popular documentation for `tkinter` on [effbot.org](https://effbot.org/) but now this documentation disappeared.

---

I found old `effbot.org` in Wayback Machine from 2020.11.12: [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: I found old effbot.org in Wayback Machine from 2020.11.12: [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) See note about bug.

Comment: nice reference 